# QLogic 12300 :: Can't use more than 6 ports

Tags: networking, infiniband

I have 2 QLogic 12300 InfiniBand switches (12300-BS01) with 36 ports. For some strange reason I am unable to connect anything to ports 7-36, it seems that only ports 1-6 are working. I Googled and found that in 12300 16-port switch (12300-BS16), licenses are needed to activate more ports and are sold in a bundle of 6, however that does not seem to apply to my IB switches.

I checked and all ports are enabled via CLI, however no led is active when I connecto something to ports 7-36. Any ideas?

Comment: If it is new, contact the vendor. If it is old, some ports may be defect.

Comment: They are not new, however the seller replaced them with 2 others which had the exact same behavior. It can't be all ports from 7 to 36 with issues, on all 4 switches.